# Save image in Full HD size using OpenCv Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

When i try to save a image using cv2.imwrite() method, it save a file in 640x480 pixel size. My web cam is FUll HD (1920×1080 px). How can i save the picture in this FHD size.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    #gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv2.imwrite('a.jpg',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, 1920)
cap.set(4, 1080)
cap.set(6, cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'))

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    #gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv2.imwrite('a.jpg',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```